# Postgresql SELECT DISTINCT ON

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the query below I'm trying to select data but need it to be distinct on the columns Book.Title and the OrderDate. I have tried using DISTINCT ON but also get multiple results back which I will also post below. Sorry if the question is a bit trivial. I'm currently in the process of learning SQL so I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to what is probably something really obvious I have missed.

How could I change the query to get the results to be formatted as so:

```
   month   |                    title                    | quantity | total_value 
-----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 February  | Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program |       15 |      899.70
 March     | C How To Program                            |        4 |      183.92
 March     | Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages          |       13 |      856.70
 March     | Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program |       21 |     1071.58
```

The query I constructed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (OrderDate, Book.Title) Book.Title, to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') AS "Order Date", 
OrderLine.Quantity AS "Order Quantity", (SUM(Quantity*UnitSellingPrice)) AS "Total Value"
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Publisher
ON Book.PublisherID=Publisher.PublisherID
INNER JOIN OrderLine
ON Book.BookID=OrderLine.BookID
INNER JOIN ShopOrder
ON OrderLine.ShopOrderID=ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
WHERE Publisher.Name='Prentice Hall'
GROUP BY book.title, OrderDate, orderline.quantity
ORDER BY OrderDate ASC;
```

The results I get:

```
                    title                    | Order Date | Order Quantity | Total Value 
---------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------
 Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program | February   |             10 |      299.90
 Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program | February   |              5 |      149.95
 C How To Program                            | March      |              3 |       68.97
 Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages          | March      |             10 |      329.50
 Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program | March      |             20 |      519.80
 C How To Program                            | March      |              1 |       22.99
 Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages          | March      |              3 |       98.85
 Internet and World Wide Web: How to Program | March      |              1 |       15.99
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things here: if you want the total quantity for each title and month, then you want to *group by* the title and month, and *sum* the quantity. You *don't* want to *group by* the quantity itself, because that would mean a new row for each distinct quantity.

That's easy to do in standard SQL (`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension, useful in a few cases *instead of* `GROUP BY`, but unnecessary here):

```
SELECT
    Book.Title,
    to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') AS "Order Date", 
    SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS "Order Quantity", 
    SUM(Quantity*UnitSellingPrice) AS "Total Value"
FROM [...]
WHERE Publisher.Name='Prentice Hall'
GROUP BY
    book.title,
    to_char(OrderDate, 'Month')
ORDER BY to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') ASC;
```

The rule of thumb is that everything in your `SELECT` clause - and your `ORDER BY` clause, which is considered to be "at the same level" - should be either:

- listed in the `GROUP BY` clause because you want a new row every time it varies
- or wrapped in an aggregate function (here `SUM()`) because you want to "roll it up" according to some rule.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining in detail. My idea of GROUP BY has been completely wrong in my head XD. Explaining it like that helped a bunch. I know I should read the Documentation in more detail but I really learn from practical hands-on learning. I do try to not resorting to asking on here when I can. Seeing as I guess constant trivial posts (Probably like mine) are pointless at times :).

Comment: No probs - `GROUP BY` seems to confuse a lot of people at first, but once you "get it", it has a logic to it which I find quite elegant. Sometimes it just won't do what you need to do, but once you understand *why* it won't, you can start approaching those problems from a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is going on, consider:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (OrderDate, Book.Title)
    Book.Title,
    OrderDate as "Actual Order Date",
    to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') AS "Order Month", ..
```

That is, the result in the post SELECTs a *different* "Order Date", really the order month, but is not the *actual* `OrderDate` value used in the DISTINCT/GROUP BY process which explains both the duplicates and incorrect aggregate results.

I suspect the desired query goes something like the following, and I've yet to find a need to use DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
  -- These are in the GROUP BY and will be DISTINCT in the result
  Book.Title,
  to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') AS "Order Month", 
  -- Non GROUP BY values should be aggregated;
  -- In this case the aggregates are over Title/Month
  SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS "Order Quantity",
  SUM(Quantity*UnitSellingPrice) AS "Total Value"
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Publisher
ON Book.PublisherID=Publisher.PublisherID
INNER JOIN OrderLine
ON Book.BookID=OrderLine.BookID
INNER JOIN ShopOrder
ON OrderLine.ShopOrderID=ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
WHERE Publisher.Name='Prentice Hall'
-- For each Title/Month
GROUP BY book.title,
         to_char(OrderDate, 'Month')       -- also grouped on Month
ORDER BY to_char(OrderDate, 'Month') ASC;  -- and sorted on Month
```